# can you please check if i done "register" function correctly in django

Tags: python, django

i am new in django , can you please check if I done "register" function in the correct way ,
without applying django forms because i find difficult to do it , so i choose this  way

my function:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    db = Customers()
    db.fname = request.POST['fname']
    db.lname = request.POST['lname']
    db.email = request.POST['email']
    db.password = make_password(request.POST['password'])
    repassword = request.POST['repassword']
    db.username = request.POST['username']
    db.save()
    if check_password(repassword, db.password):
        if User.objects.filter(username=db.username).exists():
            messages.info(request, 'Username is already taken')
            return redirect("register")
        elif User.objects.filter(email=db.email).exists():
            messages.info(request, 'Email is already taken')
            return redirect("register")
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=db.username, password=db.password, email=db.email, first_name=db.fname, last_name=db.lname)
            user.save()
            return redirect("login_user")
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Both passwords are not matching')
        return redirect(register)
else:
    return render(request, "compte/register.html")
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: I furthermore don't really understand why you do not use a Django form. This does *not* imply that you need to render these form(s). It will simplify validation, cleaning and make the view more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not write custom logic to create model objects. For example in the view you are here using, you do not check if the items appear in the `request.POST` data, furthermore you will create a `Customers` object, even if later that username turns out to be used. It thus makes the logic harder, and the the view less robust.

It is also not entirely clear to me why you repeat data in both the `Customer` and the `User`, this introduces *data duplicate*. If later a user chainges their email, then you will need to update both the `User` and the `Customer`, which makes the views more complicated. Usually one uses a `ForeignKey` for this to refer to the user. The default user model even has a `first_name` and `last_name` field, so your `Customers` model does not add that much extra information. So you can model the user with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Then we can subclass the `CreateUserForm`, and add the `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` fields:

```
# app_name/forms.py

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class CustomCreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

Then in the view, we can fix work with this form:

```
from app_name.forms import CustomCreateUserForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            Customer.objects.create(user=user)
            return redirect('login_user')
    elif 'password2' in form.errors:
        messages.info(request, 'Both passwords are not matching')
    elif 'username' in form.errors:
        messages.info(request, 'Username is already taken')
    elif 'email' in form.errors:
        messages.info(request, 'Email is already taken')
    return render(request, 'compte/register.html')
```

In the HTML form you then use `password2` instead of `repassword`, and `first_name` and `last_name` instead of `fname` and `lname`. The form will also validate that the email address is for example a valid email adress, and not just `/` or `!`.